# jQuery no conflict issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I used jQuery many times in noconflict mode as below

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and it works great every time.

Today, I used the jQuery 'before after' plugin. I used the same noconflict function but it did not work [http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/)/

I am not sure that **$.fn.extend** works with no conflict or not. Please help thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well,  `$.fn.extend` will not work if it is within your code. You'll need to use `$j.fn.extend` for your code (if $j is the name of the variable that you are using for jQuery).

Plugins should work as they normally adopt the following convention,

```
(function($){ 
    /*Plugin Code*/
})(jQuery);
```

which allows the use of $ whilst guaranteeing no conflict.

(See my answer here: [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean/2309648#2309648))

I would check your plugin to see if this holds true.

Hope this helps

Comment: The plug-in he linked does use aliasing and appears correct at first glance.

Comment: Thanks James Wiseman i am using jquery UI as well in this plug-in and found there is some problem with jqueryUI http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1686 . still things are not working :(

Comment: That link suggests the problem si fixed. What version of jQuery are you using?