# In Javascript, what does this syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this snippet when i was looking at jQuery plugins and wonder what it actually does

A jQuery plugin skeleton:

```
(function($) {
    ... 
})(jQuery);
```

And more recently in [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-persistant-sticky-notes-with-local-storage/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+nettuts+%28NETTUTS%29&utm_content=Google+Reader):

```
var STICKIES = (function () {
    ...
}());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This creates a anonymous function and calls it directly:
this is equivalent to

```
var fun = function(){};
fun();
```

its used in jquery plugins to ensure compatibility with other libraries defining a global variable '$'. in your plugin sekeleton, you wrap your plugin in a anonymous function, which receives an argument named '$' (thus overriding a global variable '$'), this anonymous function is then called with 'jQuery' as parameter, so effectively $ becomes = jQuery, but only within that anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

The first part:

```
function($) {
    ... 
}
```

creates an anonymous function.
The second part: wrapping this function with braces and `(jQuery);` cal the function with `jQuery` as argument (usable via `$` in the function).

nettuts then saves the result of the call in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The first function means that $ is overwritten by jQuery, which is useful if
you have given a different meaning to '$' in the script.