# JavaScript and Facebook - syntax explanation

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am totally new to JavaScript and the Facebook SDK. Could someone describe in English the following feature:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

i.e. the standard way of "reading" this in English. The "(function (){" bit is where I fall over. I can see what it's doing: after running this bit async goes on and does the stuff in function(), but what JavaScript feature is this and what are the components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is a little strange. The first bit

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
           xfbml: true});
};
```

Is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/function). In the context of its use, the developer could also have written:

```
function fbAsyncInit() {
  FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
           xfbml: true});
};
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KC6MK/) for an equivalent. Either way, calling is identical:

```
fbAsyncInit();
```

the following code:

```
  FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
           xfbml: true});
```

Is calling the `Init` function on the `FB` object and passing an [object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) as a parameter.

This bit here takes a little more explanation:

```
(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

This article might help: [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean/2309648#2309648)

All variables in JavaScript are 'hoisted' to global scope unless they are in a function. The convention you see is an anonymous function that is automatically invoked. We could have written:

```
function MyFunc(){
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
};
MyFunc();
```

But that would have been extra code and extra variables in memory.

Comment: ...and a global variable name, which as we all know, we should avoid globals.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped enormously.

Comment: Yeah, now I challenge you to differentiate between "jQuery syntax" and "javascript syntax". I'd love to know what you actually learned.