# A Javascript function

Tags: javascript, iife

Please explain the following way of  writing a function in javascript functions :

```
(function (){
 // some code 
})()
```

I understand the fact that because of the trailing braces " () ", the function will execute immediately but but what does enclosing the function in the braces mean?

Comment: The second is a syntax error: a function declaration must include a name.

Comment: thanks for the comment I have rephrased the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){...}){a,b); in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Edit: fixed.

Look at a normal function definition that you want to call once and only once:

```
function add(x,y) {
   var z = x + y; 
   // do something with z
}

add(2,3);
```

You could reduce this code so that you execute it straight away, there is no need to name it *add*:

```
(function(x ,y) {
   var z = x + y; 
   // do something with z
})(2,3)
```

Note how we have surrounded the function with a set of parenthesis to make it a callable expression. This pattern is often used to create a closure (capture the state of) certain variables, for example:

```
jQuery.noConflict(); //Disables the use of $ in the global scope
(function($) {

   //Safely use $ inside this function
   $('.link').click(function(e) {
      //etc
   });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This self calling anonymous pattern comes up all the time for that particular reason so I included it. No jQuery -1 :)

Answer (score 4):

As RobG pointed out, this is the only valid statement choice in your original question.

```
(function (){
 // some code 
}())
```

This is executed right after it is parsed, and provides a way to out-scope the code inside the function from the rest of your code. This is called a **closure** (see [Closures on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)) and may [help with memory leaks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/) in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing the code in a grouping operator changes it from a function declaration to a function expression (where the name is optional and usually omitted). That pattern is often called an "immediately invoked function expression" (iife) or "immediately executed function expression" (iefe).

It is used to replace a function declaration that is called just once. It is also fundamental to the module pattern.