# javascript syntax with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m)
>   [What does this JavaScript/jQuery syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309614/what-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-mean)

This is an open source jQuery popup library.

Somebody explain the code?

```
(function($){...})(jQuery);
```

for short `()();`?

What's this syntax?

How do I call `close_model` outside the code?

Here is my usage:

```
$(function() {
    $("#leanModal").leanModal({top:200});
});

$(function(){...});//again what's this syntax?
```

Codes:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.extend({

        leanModal: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                top: 100,
                overlay: 0.5
            }

            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var o = options;

                $(this).click(function(e) {

                    var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");

                    var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");

                    $("body").append(overlay);

                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function() {
                        close_modal(modal_id);
                    });

                    var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();

                    $('#lean_overlay').css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        opacity: 0
                    });

                    $('#lean_overlay').fadeTo(200, o.overlay);

                    $(modal_id).css({

                        'display': 'block',
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'opacity': 0,
                        'z-index': 11000,
                        'left': 50 + '%',
                        'margin-left': -(modal_width / 2) + "px",
                        'top': o.top + "px"

                    });

                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);

                    e.preventDefault();

                });

            });

            function close_modal(modal_id) {

                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);

                $(modal_id).css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });

            }

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you actually want to know. `$(function(){...});` is explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Answer (score 3):

The `(function ($) {})(jQuery);` is explained here:

[Plugins/Authoring jQuery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

in the "Getting Started" section. You should definitely give that a read if you want to understand jQuery plugin development.

As for your second query, `close_modal` is an *private function* that isn't accessible from outside of the closure. It's for the use of the plugin only. You can see in the `leanModal` function that it is called whenever the user clicks on the `#lean_overlay` item. If I understand the plugin correctly, you should have no need to call `close_modal` yourself.

Comment: Thanks,I do little js coding and not familiar with leanModal,the effect I want is:When my ajax response   ,I should close the previous popup form.And show up another popup telling success or error.